# rake task is not calling. from the controller action in rails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, action, rake-task

I have created a rake task in the file called `att_rec_for_emp.rake` . in this file i have the following task.

```
  task hello(parameter): :environment do

  p "{parameter}"

  end
```

how can i call this rake task in the controller action by passing parameters?

i have an action like this

```
   def call_task
     emp = Employee.first
     Rake::Task[ 'att_rec_for_emp:hello("hello world")' ].invoke
     redirect_to :root , :notice => "message fine" 
   end
```

and in `config/initialisers/rake.rb` i have the following statement.

```
  Rake.load_rakefile Rails.root.join(  'lib','tasks','att_rec_for_emp.rake' )
```

but still the task is not executing. getting the error

```
   Don't know how to build task 'att_rec_for_emp:hello'
```

Comment: Can you run the task in the command line? If yes, is this how you call it: `att_rec_for_emp:hello("hello world")` ?

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it working. Tweak from here.

Here's what I did:

**lib/tasks/att_rec_for_emp.rake**

```
task :hello, [:parameter] => :environment do |t, args|
  p "#{args[:parameter]}"
end
```

**app/controllers/your_controller.rb**

```
Rake::Task.clear
YourAppName::Application.load_tasks

class YourController < ApplicationController
  def call_task
    Rake::Task[:hello].reenable
    Rake::Task[:hello].invoke('hi world')
  end
end
```

You could also put those first two lines (above YourController class definition) in an initializer.

*Note*: Your approach of loading the Rake file in an initializer should work too but my setup is a little different. I have my entire lib directory loaded in `application.rb`.

**config/application.rb**

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib"]
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to your controller:

```
YourAppName::Application.load_tasks
```

Or, change the directory name from `initialisers` to `initializers`.

Comment: if you do: `rake -T` in your console, do you see the rake task there?

Comment: no. in the list there is no rake task. wrapping the rake task in the "namespace" is it mandatory?

Comment: add a `desc 'description of the rake task'` just before the `task name_of_task`, then it should appear when you do: `rake -T`